# Counting most of entries (mode) in hive data

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am having trouble writing a query to find the hour of the day that most number of tweets was generated by users on March 6, 2010.

I have created the table for my twitter data.

```
create table twitter.full_text_ts as
select id, cast(concat(substr(ts,1,10), ' ', substr(ts,12,8)) as timestamp) as        ts, lat, lon, tweet
from full_text;
```

now I need to query it to find which hour of the day had the most tweets on a particular day.

I am able to see all the timestamps (ts) of the tweets on any particular day by entering

```
select ts 
from twitter.full_text_ts
where to_date(ts) = '2010-03-06'
order by ts desc;
```

this outputs:

```
2010-03-06  02:10:01 
2010-03-06  02:11:15 and so on.
```

What i would like to do is group them by the hour so I can see what hour has the most entries.

Thanks,

Cale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hour()` function:

```
select hour(ts), count(*) as cnt 
from twitter.full_text_ts
where to_date(ts) = '2010-03-06'
group by hour(ts)
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: Gave me a count of the number of entries in each hour of the specified date. Will work for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select DATEPART(HH, ts) [Hour], COUNT(*) [Count]
from twitter.full_text_ts 
where to_date(ts) = '2010-03-06' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH, ts) [Hour] 
order by 1 desc;
```

Comment: Will try this and let you know. Thanks Noor!